# How to use conditional operator for validation of a field in vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, validation, vuejs2

I have a text field  like this:

```
<input name="max-amount" v-validate="is_req=='required' : 'req' : ''" v-model="maxAmount">
```

I want to validate this field on multiple conditions like if is_req==true then only i will validate it, if in is_req there is max amount and max amount then max and min validation should be fired.

Answer (score 0):

I would you suggest to use the `computed` to create multiple validation rules.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: "invalid"
  },
  computed: {
    valid() {
      const text = this.text.trim()
      return text.length > 0 && text !== 'invalid'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="text" />
  <button :disabled="!valid">Button</button>
</div>
```